# System.AccessViolationException when passing struct to unmanaged code

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

I'm trying to use an unmanaged API from C#, and banging my head against the wall. (I'm rather a beginner when it comes to PInvoke.)

The relevant parts of the header file look like this:

```
#define CTAPICALL       __stdcall
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

extern  BOOL    CTAPICALL   ctTagReadEx(HANDLE,LPCSTR,LPSTR,DWORD,CT_TAGVALUE_ITEMS*);      /* read extended data from tag          */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`CT_TAGVALUE_ITEMS` looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    DWORD                   dwLength;                           /* size, in bytes, of this structure    */
    unsigned __int64        nTimestamp;                         /*  timestamp                           */
    unsigned __int64        nValueTimestamp;                    /*  value timestamp                     */
    unsigned __int64        nQualityTimestamp;                  /*  quality timestamp                   */
    BYTE                    bQualityGeneral;                    /*  quality general                     */
    BYTE                    bQualitySubstatus;                  /*  quality substatus                   */
    BYTE                    bQualityLimit;                      /*  quality limit                       */
    BYTE                    bQualityExtendedSubstatus;          /*  quality extended substatus          */
    UINT                    nQualityDatasourceErrorCode;        /*  quality datasource error            */
    BOOLEAN                 bOverride;                          /*  quality override flag               */
    BOOLEAN                 bControlMode;                       /*  quality control mode flag           */
}   CT_TAGVALUE_ITEMS;
```

My C# method declaration:

```
    [DllImport("ctapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool ctTagReadEx(
        IntPtr hCTAPI,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string tag,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder value,
        int length,
        CtTagValueItems tagValueItems);
```

The C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CtTagValueItems
{
    public int dwLength;
    public ulong nTimestamp;
    public ulong nValueTimestamp;
    public ulong nQualityTimestamp;
    public byte bQualityGeneral
    public byte bQualitySubstatus;
    public byte bQualityLimit;
    public byte bQualityExtendedSubstatus;
    public uint nQualityDatasourceErrorCode;
    public uint bOverride;
    public uint bControlMode;
}
```

When I call it like this **(from a test assembly built as x86)**, I get a `System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory`:

```
StringBuilder valueBuilder = new StringBuilder(300);
CtTagValueItems tagValueItems = new CtTagValueItems {dwLength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (CtTagValueItems))};
bool ok = CTAPI.ctTagReadEx(new IntPtr(handle), "TIC_Hold_PV", valueBuilder, valueBuilder.Capacity, tagValueItems);
```

I've been trying all kinds of things, like using `LayoutKind.Explicit` and/or `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`, but to no avail.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Don't use `Cdecl`. The C code is clear, it's `Stdcall`. Don't use `SetLastError = true`. That's for Windows API functions. Pass the struct by `ref`. `BOOLEAN` is a single byte.

Comment: SetLastError is used by the API being wrapped (CitectSCADA API). The error codes are Citect error codes if they are above 0x10000000, otherwise they are Windows error codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why did you map `UINT` as `ushort`. Doesn't it have 4 bytes?
2. The native `BOOLEAN` type maps to 4 bytes, AFAIK.
3. You need to pass `CtTagValueItems` by ref (as class or `ref`).
4. Check the calling convention.
5. Check whats written in the comments.

Comment: 1. Fixed (edited the original question)    

2. In `windows.h`, BOOL is declared as an `int`. Isn't that 4 bytes?    

3. When I try to pass it as a `ref`, I get the following exception:    
`A call to PInvoke function 'Citect.Util!Citect.Util.CTAPI::ctTagReadEx' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.`

Comment: 2. `bool bOverride` => `uint bOverride` (or use a marshal option). 4. `HANDLE` maps to `IntPtr`. So: `IntPtr hCTAPI`. Be careful with all the type mappings. Besides the mappings I think you got it right.

Comment: I still get the same error. I'm actually adding this missing method to an existing, working, C# wrapper, which uses `uint` for the handles, so I don't think the `HANDLE` is causing the problem.

Comment: @dabide uint is clearly wrong on x64. Maybe you got lucky so far, but if the handle value is big enough your code will break. Can you update the question to the newest code you have?

Comment: I have updated the question. I'm calling the code from a test assembly built as x86 using NUnit. The other methods work, BTW.

Comment: @dabide the struct *must* be by-ref (just like in C). The fact that we are getting a different error does not mean that this is wrong. Please try again by-ref and post the code.

Comment: I actually used ref, I just forgot to edit that part. The reason for the `PInvoke`error was that I had left in `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`.  
I finally got it to work: I had to add the `ref`, and BOOLEAN is a byte. Please edit your answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I also had to add `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)`, as @gabba suggested.

Comment: `BOOLEAN`maps to one byte, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in alignment. try somting like

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't change anything. I still get the same exception.

Comment: Try to double check type maping as usr says.

Comment: The type mapping was indeed the problem. With the tips from @usr, your suggestion and `WinDef.h`, I got it to work.

Comment: `Pack=1` is wrong. Unless the header file has a `#pragma(pack)` that we cannot see.

Comment: Indeed, it has:  
`#pragma pack(push, 1)` :-)

Comment: I didn't know until you asked! My experience with C is limited to a course 20 years ago, where we went through K&R... :-)

Comment: 8) I am glad that the problem was solved. Often the problem in alignment. Iam writed it without to look for #pragma(pack) in code. I hope it helps some one

Answer (score 1):

Where does the `handle` variable in your C# call come from?

I much prefer to use `IntPtr` in my `DllImport` method definitions. It seems easier to manage and marshal that way.

I've changed quite a bit of the `struct` definition because I don't have the same defines as you. I also don't have much of a body in my `ctTagReadEx` function (I'll try to flesh it out to make sure the parameters passed in match the parameters received). But this works for me.

**Update:** It looks like all the parameters and struct values are passed correctly.

**C**

```
typedef struct
{
    int                     dwLength;                           /* size, in bytes, of this structure    */
    unsigned long           nTimestamp;                         /*  timestamp                           */
    unsigned long           nValueTimestamp;                    /*  value timestamp                     */
    unsigned long           nQualityTimestamp;                  /*  quality timestamp                   */
    int                     bQualityGeneral;                    /*  quality general                     */
    int                     bQualitySubstatus;                  /*  quality substatus                   */
    int                     bQualityLimit;                      /*  quality limit                       */
    int                     bQualityExtendedSubstatus;          /*  quality extended substatus          */
    unsigned int            nQualityDatasourceErrorCode;        /*  quality datasource error            */
    int                     bOverride;                          /*  quality override flag               */
    int                     bControlMode;                       /*  quality control mode flag           */
}   CT_TAGVALUE_ITEMS;


CTAPICALL int ctTagReadEx(void *, const char *, char *, int, CT_TAGVALUE_ITEMS *);

int ctTagReadEx(void * hCTAPI, const char * tag, char * value, int length, CT_TAGVALUE_ITEMS *tagValueItems) {
    return 15;
}
```

**C#**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CtTagValueItems {
    public int dwLength;
    public ulong nTimestamp;
    public ulong nValueTimestamp;
    public ulong nQualityTimestamp;
    public int bQualityGeneral;
    public int bQualitySubstatus;
    public int bQualityLimit;
    public int bQualityExtendedSubstatus;
    public uint nQualityDatasourceErrorCode;
    public int bOverride;
    public int bControlMode;
}

[DllImport("ctapi.dll")]
static extern int ctTagReadEx(IntPtr hCTAPI, IntPtr tag, IntPtr value, int length, IntPtr tagValueItems);

public void TestMe() {

    var tagValueItems = new CtTagValueItems();
    var tagValueItemsPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CtTagValueItems)));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(tagValueItems, tagValueItemsPtr, true);

    var tag = "tag";
    var tagPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(tag);

    var value = "value";
    var valuePtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(value);

    int length = value.Length;

    var result = ctTagReadEx(IntPtr.Zero, tagPtr, valuePtr, length, tagValueItemsPtr);
    if (result != 15) throw new Exception();

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tagValueItemsPtr);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tagPtr);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(valuePtr);
}
```